# Trouble Connecting to MSSQL via TSQL on Ubuntu

Tags: sql-server, ubuntu

I'm using tsql to confirm connectivity to a ms sql server instance:

```
tsql -S "66.239.210.201\[instance name],1481" -U [username]
Password: [password]
```

Output:

```
locale is "en_US.UTF-8"
locale charset is "UTF-8"
using default charset "UTF-8"
[counts from 1 to 16]
16There was a problem connecting to the server
```

Log freetds.log

```
> log.c:196:Starting log file for FreeTDS 0.91
>         on 2016-02-11 14:01:46 with debug flags 0x4fff.
> iconv.c:330:tds_iconv_open(0x1eaea3b0, UTF-8)
> iconv.c:187:local name for ISO-8859-1 is ISO-8859-1
> iconv.c:187:local name for UTF-8 is UTF-8
> iconv.c:187:local name for UCS-2LE is UCS-2LE
> iconv.c:187:local name for UCS-2BE is UCS-2BE
> iconv.c:349:setting up conversions for client charset "UTF-8"
> iconv.c:351:preparing iconv for "UTF-8" <-> "UCS-2LE" conversion
> iconv.c:391:preparing iconv for "ISO-8859-1" <-> "ISO-8859-1" conversion
> iconv.c:394:tds_iconv_open: done
> net.c:934:tds7_get_instance_port(66.239.210.201, [redacted], 1481)
> net.c:985:tds7_get_instance_port: timed out on try 0 of 16
....
> net.c:985:tds7_get_instance_port: timed out on try 15 of 16
> net.c:1057:instance port is 0
> login.c:436:invalid port number
> mem.c:615:tds_free_all_results()
```

Any idea what I'm doing wrong?  I've tried specifying different ports with the -p flag, but always get the same message.  I've also tried placing an entry in freetds.log for:

```
[sqlserver]
host = 66.239.210.201
instance = MSSQLSERVER
tds version = auto
```

and using it with tsql -S sqlserver, which results in an identical error file as aforementioned.

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0):

Your log says

> > net.c:934:tds7_get_instance_port(66.239.210.201, [redacted], 1481)
> >     net.c:985:tds7_get_instance_port: timed out on try 0 of 16
> >     ....
> >     net.c:985:tds7_get_instance_port: timed out on try 15 of 16
> >     net.c:1057:instance port is 0

This means the host and port pair is not accessible to your application. There can be various reason such as firewall. or access rule mentioned at the SQL server end.

As a first step you can try telnetting to the host and port pair to check if it is accessible